# Compare values from array with every other value

Tags: php, foreach

I have an array like so:

```
$array = [['name'=> 'one'], ['name'=>'two'],['name'=> 'three'], ['name'=>'four']];
```

I want to compare/print every combination from that array:

one -> two
one -> three
...
two -> three
two -> four

and so on...

I tried

```
<?php foreach ($compares as $k1 => $v1 ){
    echo $v1->id.'<br>';

    foreach ($compares2 as $k2 => $v2 ){
        if($k1 == $k2) echo $v2->id.'<br>';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you please write the exact result you want from that array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pavels answer seem to be right, maybe you should check your values for duplicates?

```
<?php

$array = [['id'=> 'one'],['id'=>'two'],['id'=> 'three'],['id'=>'four']];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array)-1; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i+1; $j < count($array); $j++) {
        echo $array[$i]['id'] . ' - ';
        echo $array[$j]['id'] . '<br>';
    }
} 

?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
one - two
one - three
one - four
two - three
two - four
three - four
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your requirements correctly (I can modify it if you want). Have a look at this example:

```
<?php

$array = [
    ['name'=> 'one'], 
    ['name'=>'two'],
    ['name'=> 'three'], 
    ['name'=>'four']
];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array)-1; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i+1; $j < count($array); $j++) {
        echo $array[$i]['name'] . ' > ';
        echo $array[$j]['name'] . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Pawel, thanks. But this way it compares (with 100 values) from 100 to 1 ... it is less to the end

Comment: I would like to have some example of result, because I am affraid that I don't understand your goal in 100%.